# Transform CircleRange in SpatialPolygon in R

Tags: r, polygon, spatial, r-sp

A very common procedure is to transform lines and borders into `SpatialPolygons` objects using the `Polygon` functions from the **sp** package. But is it possible to transform other object classes into `SpatialPolygons`? I use the function `circles` from **dismo** to create a circumference with specific radius distance from a known spatial point. This function returns an object of class `CirclesRange`.

```
circ<-circles(spcoords,d=100000)

class(circ)
[1] "CirclesRange"
attr(,"package")
[1] "dismo"
```

When I try to convert the `CirclesRange` object into `SpatialPolygons`, the following error occurs:

```
Error: is.integer(pO) is not TRUE
```

Then, I have searched other ways to transform this object, but I have not been successful. I think that first it is necessary to transform "circ" into another class and then try to convert it to `SpatialPolygons`, but I can't find information about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `str(circ)`, the desired `SpatialPolygons` object is already part of the created object. You simply need to run `circ@polygons` to extract the polygon. Here is some sample code based on the `meuse` dataset.

```
## sample data
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~ x + y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")

## circle around the first 'meuse' feature (top-right corner)
circ <- circles(meuse[1, ], d = 1000, lonlat = FALSE)

poly <- circ@polygons
proj4string(poly) <- proj4string(meuse)

## display data
library(latticeExtra)

spplot(meuse, "elev", scales = list(draw = TRUE),
       col.regions = topo.colors(100), key.space = "right") + 
  as.layer(spplot(poly, fill = "transparent", lwd = 2))
```

[image: spplot]

Comment: fdetsch is right! However if you don't mind using another package the function `gBuffer` from the `library(rgeos)` does the same of `library(dismo)` but returning an object of class `SpatialPolygons`. Using `data(meuse)` as suggested by @fdetsch it would be: `poly <- gBuffer(meuse[1, ], width = 1000)`